# python Извлечение ключей из json файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

И Так,у меня есть json файл в нём хранятся **"id":{"report":1}**
На данном скрине здесь всего лишь два id пользователя,но их может быть любое количество,вопрос заключается в том как получить все id пользователей в этом файле в масиве(**Только id, без report**)
[image: ***]

Comment: json.loads("""{....}""").keys()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

data = json.load(open("report.json",'rb'))
ids = data.keys() #-> list с ключами

for id in data:
    id #-> ключики по одному
```

Comment: По-моему, `dict.keys()` возвращает `set`-подобный контейнер, а не список)